# How to update opportunity records closedate as today using dml statements?

Tags: dml-operations

I am trying to update the all opportunity records close date as today using dml statements. Can anyone please help me

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stock Exchange (SFSE)! Can you add more details like what have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/380884/edit) your question and add those details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //Query all the opportunity records via SOQL.
    List<Opportunity> lstOpp = new List<Opportunity>();
    lstOpp = [Select id,name,stage,status,closeddate from Opportunity]; 

List<Opportunity> updateOpportunity = new List<Opportunity>();
if(lstOpp!=null && lstOpp.size()>0){
for(Opportunity opp: lstOpp){
opp.closeddate = system.today();
updateOpportunity.add(opp);
}
}
//Update records via DML
if(updateOpportunity!=null && updateOpportunity.size()>0){
update updateOpportunity;
}
```